# Two checkboxes, can only select one

Tags: android, checkbox, layout

I'm working on a login screen where basically you can selected whether you want a 4 digit PIN access or a swipe method security; the way I want this to look is that there are two checkboxes in the layout, initially they're both unchecked. When you select one, it gets checked, but then if you try to select the other one, it unchecks the first one automatically. I have two checkboxes defined in the layout, but I'm a little confused by what I'd have to reference to force the unchecking.

```
public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view){
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox)view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.setupCheckBox1:
            if(checked){

            }
```

Basically, I know that something has to go into that if{} statement that unchecks setupCheckBox2 automatically, but I'm just unsure of what has to be made false. Any help appreciated!

Also, I realize this is kind of a one line answer, if anyone has any good references to checkboxes in Android, I wouldn't mind reading up on that either, I'm kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: Why don't you just use a radio button group, they have that functionality already. Checkboxes by design should allow multiple checks within a group, Radio Buttons should not.

Comment: @TronicZomB - the question is about CHECKBOXES - just saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android developers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133373/2315997

Comment: will try this .

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple, Try this code

```
public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    cbx_hindi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                cbx_english.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    cbx_english.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                cbx_hindi.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code and see selected ckeck box value in logcat.....

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

        CheckBox hindi, english;
        Button submit;
        String language;


      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     hindi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    english = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

         @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.submit:


        if(hindi.isChecked())
            {

                language="hindi" ; 

            }


            if(english.isChecked())
            {

                language="english" ; 

            }


            if((hindi.isChecked()==true)&&(english.isChecked()==true))
                     {

            Toast.makeText(DrivingTestActivity.this,
            "please select one language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                      }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("language" + language);
             }
                      break;

        default:
            break;
        }

               } 
              }
```